# BufferedReader and BufferedInputStream default buffer is 8192 of what? chars and bytes respectively?

Tags: java

Docs don't tell what this magic number 8192 means.

I think it is bytes for BufferedInputStream and chars for BufferedWriter. Right?

```
BufferedInputStream(InputStream in, int size)


BufferedWriter(Writer out, int sz)
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not check the source code? BufferedWriter has a char array, so it is characters. BufferedInputStream deals with bytes, so there it is bytes. In other words you are correct.

EDIT:

```
public BufferedWriter(Writer out, int sz) {
    // Code here removed for brevity, allocation below
    cb = new char[sz];
```

Comment: DiabolicWords don't agree

Comment: Then DiabolicWords needs to check his facts. The source code comes with the JDK and is the final truth. I have added the relevant lines above.